# Can I prevent a package from redefining a command?

Tags: symbols, packages, characters

I like to use runes and letters from other non-standard alphabets as mathematical symbols. However, now the `allrunes` package is interfering with my other mathematical typesetting. Take this minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{allrunes}

\begin{document}
$\bar{x}$
\end{document}
```

I get these error messages:

```
LaTeX Warning: Command \bar invalid in math mode on input line 6.

! LaTeX Error: Command \bar unavailable in encoding OT1.
```

I think that the problem lies in `allrunes.sty`, which redefines the `\bar` command:

```
\newcommand{\DeclareRuneSeparators}[1]{%
  [..]
  \DeclareTextSymbol{\bar}{#1}{33}        % !
  [..]
} % end of newcommand{\DeclareRuneSeparators}
```

**Is there a way to prevent `allrunes` from redefining `\bar`, so that I can still use it as the usual math symbol? Or any other way of recovering the functionality of `\bar`?**

The exact same happens not just for `\bar`, but also for `\dot`.

Comment: Beware that `allrunes` also does some other redefinitions that are quite disputable. In particular it redefines `\bfseries` and this can lead to severe problems.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

before loading the package do

```
\let\origbar\bar
\let\origdot\dot
\usepackage{...}
\let\bar\origbar
\let\dot\origdot
```

Note that in some cases you may need to postpone the redoing until after `\begin{document}`

One might wonder why you are using runes in a documnt with math?

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly! Runes are useful as an additional source of mathematical symbols without any predefined meaning or connotation, and they are kind of entertaining as well.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation (yet) for an upvote.

Comment: @TobiasFritz, I do not think that is a good idea. Inventing additional mathematical symbols often ends up giving headaches to those trying to typeset what ever the mathematician have invented. Did you have a look in the symbols list instead?

Comment: that's a good point which I'll have to keep in mind. In the present case, we use them only for some simple examples, so it shouldn't be harmful, but I'll reconsider it.

Comment: I am explaining how to transform images represented in matrix form, and runes make  beautiful line-art symbols that are easy to be put into matrices.