# Prevent "esint" package from redefining \oint

Tags: symbols

The [`esint` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/esint?lang=en) provides additional commands for typesetting integrals, e.g. closed multiple integrals. However, it also redefines the single closed integral `\oint`, in essence making the circle larger. Is there any way to prevent this from happening and preserve the ordinary symbol?

I have tried following the procedure laid out in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/151076/63353), but it doesn't seem to work, at least on my end.

MWE (comment out lines 3-5 to see regular behaviour):

```
\documentclass{article}

\let\origoint\oint
\usepackage{esint}
\let\oint\origoint

\begin{document}

\[ \oint \]

\end{document}
```

[image: With esint loaded.]

[image: Without esint loaded.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\oint` is defined as `\ointop\nolimits`, so you need to save `\ointop`, not `\oint`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\let\origointop\ointop
\usepackage{esint}
\let\ointop\origointop

\begin{document}

\[ \oint \]

\end{document}
```